# Validity of error formulas for numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

Are error formulas for numerical methods appliable for any step size, or can they only be applied when the method converges?

The example that motivated this question was the following formula for the error of Heun's method (Runge-Kutta order 2).

$E = (\frac{1}{4}||f_y||_{\infty} ||y^{(2)}||_{\infty} - \frac{1}{12}||y^{(3)}||_{\infty})h^3$

This formula grossly underestimates the error when the step size is big. (Note, however, that I do not know if this formula is correct)

Comment: Give an example of what formulas and methods you have in mind.

Comment: Runge-Kutta methods for solving ODEs

Comment: It depends what error you're quoting. Most commonly you quote local truncation error, then you try to prove stability, then assuming your bound on the local truncation error was $Ch^{k+1}$, your bound on the global truncation error is $C'h^k$, where sometimes you can represent $C'$ explicitly. But you have to prove stability first, which is typically the hard part.

Comment: If you have a formula that states $E=a-b-c$, then the bound you get is, by the triangle inequality, $|E|\le |a|+|b|+|c|$. Which in your case without further insights should give $$\|E\|\le (\frac{5}{12}\|y^{(3)}\|_\infty+\frac14\|f_y\|_\infty\|y^{(2)}\|_\infty)·|h|^3.$$